# Store values from an array in new array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have an array `prejobs`, and I want to store some of its elements in a new array `demojobs`. I tried the following code:

```
@pre.jobs.map do |job|
    @demojobs = Demojob.new(job)
end
render json: @demojobs
```

But I get an `undefined method 'stringify_keys'` error. Is there any good way to perform this?

Comment: can you try `render json: @demojsobs.as_json` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both `Prejob` and `Demojob` are active record models, you should use `attributes` in the constructor call. Also rather build a new array with `map` or append to it than assign to a new value to a var in every iteration step..

```
@demojobs = @pre.jobs.map do |job|
  Demojob.new(job.attributes.except(:id))
end
render json: @demojobs
```

EDIT:

To add some custom attributes, you can merge them to the hash or set them manually:

```
@demojobs = @pre.jobs.map do |job|
  Demojob.new(job.attributes.except(:id).merge(attr1: val1, attr1: val2))
end
render json: @demojobs

@demojobs = @pre.jobs.map do |job|
  Demojob.new(job.attributes.except(:id)).tap do |dj|
    dj.attr1 = val1
    dj.attr2 = val2
  end
end
render json: @demojobs
```

Comment: Thankoyou for your answer. Its add same data from Prejob to Demojob but if i want to add some  custom attributies in demojob active record model then how can i do?

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think You should try like this

```
@demojobsarray = Array.new
    @pre.jobs.map do |job|
        @demojobsarray.push(job)
    end
@demojobs=Demojob.new(@demojobsarray)
render json: @demojobs
```